# Google AppMaker Id (primary key) missing or null on Save

Tags: google-app-maker

I have a datasource in manual save mode. When I create the item and persist the changes, I get an error message, saying Id field is null. Id field is the primary key and hence cannot be assigned through front end. Any ideas why AppMaker thinks it is missing.

[image]

Code is this

```
widget.datasource.createItem({
  success: function(){
    app.datasources.CountyManualSave.saveChanges({
      success: function() {console.log('yey');},
      failure: function(e) {showSnackbar(e.message);}
    });
  },
  failure: function(e) {showSnackbar(e.message);}
});
```

Here's the image, that shows it is the primary key. Doing the insert through the Mysql client works without problems.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure what was wrong but I unclicked the auto increment and reclicked the auto increment under field Id. Previewed again. Things worked. I am leaving this question here in case somebody questions their sanity. This is to show that environment is not always stable.

Comment: Didnot work for me.
My version of issue:
Using exact structure to save the data as provided in template: https://developers.google.com/appmaker/scripting/api/client#CreateDataSource

The createItem successCallback is called with exact data sent from client with `_key` and `Id` null.
The trigger onBeforeCreate at model Events also does not trigger.

Comment: I think it is the back end sometimes not compiling right... I'd suggest renaming the column back and forth.. that also sometimes worked...